# Fail in release/Adhoc build But work in debug mode (ios)

Tags: ios, ipad, debugging, sockets, tcpsocket

Running a sample application in background mode(ios) using TCP sockets.It give message(a local notification ) when client send any message and wait for another message.It works fine when the application run in debugging, but crashes in release mode after 10 seconds.
used: xcode 4.2 & iPad 2 for testing..

This is the code I'm working with:

```
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

 CFReadStreamRef hReadStream;

 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sockfd < 0) printf("Sockfd Error\n");

 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
 portNo = 3600;//atoi(argv);
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portNo);
 if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
   sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
 printf("bind error\n");



listen(sockfd,5); 

clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

newsockfd = 1;


while(newsockfd)
{  

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                       (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                       &clilen);
    NSLog(@"newsockfd create %d\n",newsockfd);

    remoteAdd = inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr);

    //cout << remoteAdd << " port =  "  << cli_addr.sin_port << endl;

    portNo = cli_addr.sin_port;

    #if defined(__IPHONE_4_0) && !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)

        NSLog(@"newsocket %d\n",newsockfd);

        // Only do this if it is a SipSocket we are watching
        if (newsockfd)
        {
            // Set it to non-blocking
            //int set = 0;
            //ioctl(newsockfd, FIONBIO, reinterpret_cast<int>(&set));

            CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket (kCFAllocatorDefault, newsockfd,
                                          &hReadStream, NULL);
            if (CFReadStreamSetProperty(hReadStream,
                                        kCFStreamNetworkServiceType,
                                        kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP) != TRUE)
            {
                // An error occured, delete the stream
                if(hReadStream != NULL)
                {
                    CFReadStreamClose(hReadStream);
                    CFRelease(hReadStream);
                    hReadStream = NULL;
                }

                //return -1;
            }
            else NSLog(@" >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> property set Here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n");

            if (CFReadStreamOpen(hReadStream) != TRUE)
            {
                // An error occured, delete the stream
                if(hReadStream != NULL)
                {
                    CFReadStreamClose(hReadStream);
                    CFRelease(hReadStream);
                    hReadStream = NULL;
                }

                // return -1;
            }
            else NSLog(@"read....\n");
        }
    #endif      

    [self test];
}
```

Crash report in device log :

```
"Application 'Demo' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9" &
"unknown ReportCrash[10915] <Error>: Saved crashreport to
/var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/servertest_2011-12-13-163920_EyeBalls-iPad.plist
using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0"
```

Trying to found the bug but it works fine in debug mode Exactly no error found in device log or debug window..Please help me :(

Comment: What is your compiler option ? is it llvm 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

you can switch your compiler option to llvm gcc4.2 . I guess it issue related to clang.
hope it will work fine.